# SwiftUI unable to click buttons in overlay/popover screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that I present at the top of other views like a popover view, inside the view I have a couple of buttons. When I add a single button in the overplayed view and tap the button it works. However if I added multiple buttons and try to tap the buttons they don't work. Instead it clicks to the components bellow the view.

I would like to add multiple buttons and click them on the overlay view, I'm not sure what my mistake is on this code:

Here is my code:

```
struct MenuContent: View {

    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("tapped button")
                        }) {

                            VStack {
                                Text("Rev")

                                Image("trash.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            }

                        }.background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

OverlayView

```
struct OverlayMenu: View {

    let width: CGFloat

    @Binding var show: Bool

    var body: some View {

        return ZStack {
                HStack {
                    MenuContent()
                        .frame(width: self.width, height: 160)
                        .cornerRadius(10, antialiased: false)
                        .offset(x: self.show ? 0 : -self.width, y: 285)
                        .animation(.spring())

                    Spacer()
                }
            .shadow(radius: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var show = true

    var body: some View {

        OverlayMenu(width: 350,
                      show: $show)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some trouble with `List` rows and tap gestures on them. You can deal with it if you want or you may try `VStack` instead of `List` and use `Divider` to divide "rows" and taps on the buttons will be handle as you expect. I changed your example a little to show how it works, I think you can handle design by yourself then:

```swift
struct MenuContent: View {

    @State var hits = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text("\(hits)")

            Divider().frame(width: 250)

            ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
                ButtonsLine(hits: self.$hits)
                Divider().frame(width: 250)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ButtonsLine: View {

    @Binding var hits: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<4) { value in
                Button(action: {
                    print("tapped button")
                    self.hits += value + 1
                }) {
                    ButtonDesign()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonDesign: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Rev")
                .foregroundColor(.black)

            Image(systemName: "trash")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)

        }
        .shadow(radius: 20)
    }

}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , the only issue is that the index of ButtonDesign() resets every row, which makes it difficult to use the solution when u have say 8 ButtonDesigns